# Auto-scroll LyX window while typing

Tags: lyx, interfaces

Is it possible to define a setting or something to fix window scrolling in LyX to a specific relative position?
That is, say my view is set such that I'm typing on the third of the visible lines, and I want the window to scroll down automatically while hitting enter or moving on to the next line to stay on the third visible line.

Has anyone heard of anything like that?
Sorry if I wasn't entirely clear, English isn't mother tongue...

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! This sounds like an editor feature: which one do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! I'm not exactly sure what you mean by editor- I  downloaded Lyx from lyx.org, so I guess they only have one editor there.

Comment: I don't think that regular editor interfaces provide such a thing. Try `vim` to define such behviour. `emacs` might work too. But after all keep in mind that `Ed is the UNIX Editor`.

Comment: @ikrabbe As the OP uses LyX (i.e. not a normal text editor), Vim/Emacs are irrelevant.  Johnathan: I can't see anything like that in the preferences at first glance, so I think the answer is 'no'. If I'm right about that, your only option is, I think, to post a feature request at http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome, and live with the current situation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "regular editor interfaces" -> LyX. That he uses lyx was not clear at the time I wrote the comment.

Comment: @ikrabbe Tip: use `@username` as I did here to ensure that users are notified of comments. I can't really say I understand your comment (if you didn't know he used LyX -- which isn't a text editor -- how can you say it doesn't provide that feature), but this isn't the place for that discussion. Ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) if you feel it's necessary to clarify.

Comment: @TorbjørnT That's why I didn't wrote "this is not available in LyX", but I wrote "in regular editor interfaces", which means something like >90% of integrated or dedicated editor programs. You are right this is not the place for the discussion. I just tried the `@username` thing, here.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling with arrow <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> maintain always the cursor visible in the window between the first and last line of the screen, so I guess that the major problem is when you use the scrolling bar (or the equivalent scroll wheel of the mouse) and the cursor go away.

I think that the closest feature to what you're looking for is the `toggle-cursor-follows-scrollbar` Lyx function, that is off by default. To change it go to menu <kbd>Tool</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > In the left tree go to  <kbd>Edition</kbd> > <kbd>Control</kbd> > and check the first box in the right.

Now the cursor, according to the text format, will remain  between the 1-3 first lines when scrolling up or the 1-3 last lines when scrolling down with the scroll wheel, so it is more easy to find the cursor and check the surrounding text that using the arrow keys.

N.B.: In the same preferences you can increase the size (visibility) of the cursor.